# Are there any good ant visualization programs out there?

Tags: java, ant, utility

I am looking for a utility that will suck in an ant build file and present a graphical display of the targets and properties available to that target. Please don't respond with 'VisualAnt' I own it and it sucks.

Answer (score 6):

I use yWorks Ant Explorer.  It runs as a stand alone app.  It's pretty good.  Apparently there is an Eclipse plugin as well but I haven't been able to locate that.

It's free.  Not sure if yWorks still develops it.  You can download the jar [here](http://myblog.chaiware.org/2009/02/ant-explorer-graphical-ant-build-tool.html) and [here](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Development-Scripts-js/yWorks-Ant-Explorer-29247.html).  After download, just create a bat file with this command:

java -jar antexplorer.jar

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Elements of Ant Style](http://wiki.apache.org/ant/TheElementsOfAntStyle) wiki page. They have a link there for a XSLT style sheet that makes a build file browsable. [Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-antxsl/examples/example2/ant2html.xsl) is a link for it. The wiki page also shows how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Eclipse user, take a look at [Ant Visualization Plugin for Eclipse](https://bitbucket.org/satyagraha.1956/ant_vis/wiki/Home)