# Need a tool for visualizing ant execution flows and properties

Tags: ant, build-process, visualization, modeling

I'm trying to figure out how the [DITA Open Toolkit](http://dita-ot.sourceforge.net) performs DITA to XHTML conversions, and it's difficult since the process is managed by dozens of ant targets spread over multiple ant files.

I need a tool that can provide a visualization of the execution flow plus property dependencies of an ant invocation. [VizAnt](http://vizant.sourceforge.net/) and [Grand](http://www.ggtools.net/grand/) only graph target invocations, so I'm looking for something heavier-duty. Ideally, such a tool would identify the order of target invocations, as well as property values live at invocation, and properties, files, directories, classpath entries, etc. that are referenced in the body of a target.

My first thought was to manually graph it all in OmniGraffle, but the complexity quickly became unmanageable. Surely there's something more recent out there?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425842/are-there-any-good-ant-visualization-programs-out-there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[yWorks](http://www.yworks.com/en/index.html) [Ant Explorer](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t42463.html) is kind of cool.

[Graphical representation of the ANT build targets and dependencies http://www.yworks.com/demos/images/ae1.jpg](http://www.yworks.com/demos/images/ae1.jpg)

[Execute code through the GUI explorer of the ANT build file http://www.yworks.com/demos/images/ae3.jpg](http://www.yworks.com/demos/images/ae3.jpg)

Run it by executing the jar file: `java -jar antexplorer.jar`

It looks like yWorks no longer supports it and have removed it from their website.  Links that [used to go to Ant Explorer](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_antexplorer_about.htm) now just take you to their product listing page.

But there appear to be several places that have it available for download:

- http://yworks-ant-explorer.software.informer.com/
- http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Development-Scripts-js/yWorks-Ant-Explorer-29247.html
- http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=135

Comment: This looks promising, but the only download I could find won't work on my Mac, and as you said support seems non-existent. I'll keep looking, though. Thanks!

Comment: It's a jar file that brings up a swing GUI.  Why won't it work on your Mac?