# understand complex ant build files

Tags: eclipse, ant, ide, intellij-idea

I have a quite complex ant build system comprised of many build.xml files in different folders. I want to crack on it.

Is there any IDE support (in `Eclipse` or `Intellij`) for me to jump to target definitions, taskdefs' definitions, macrodefs' etc.?

Besides "ant -v", any other way to ease the understanding of the flow of target execution?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no new tools since a while.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255014/need-a-tool-for-visualizing-ant-execution-flows-and-properties

Answer (score 0):

In 2007, I wrote an [article](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200711/ant_dependency_graph.html) on the options to display Ant targets and dependencies visually.  I think they will still work.  I also had to deal with a large Ant codebase and the visualization really helped.  (I used a tiny Ant build for the article but the tools do scale well.)

Answer (score 0):

The default eclipse distribution contains an Ant XML Editor which helps navigating Ant files. Simply right click the Ant file and select "open with -> Other -> Ant Editor".

You can jump to target definitions by pressing CTRL and clicking on it. You can also set breakpoints in your ant scripts. If you start the ant script in debug mode from eclipse, execution will stop at your breakpoints and you can debug your ant script like you would any other code.