# Ant visual analysis?

Tags: java, ant

I have to look into some complicated `Ant` files which include targets of other `Ant` files and these others, targets from the original etc.
Is there a (visual) tool that helps understand `Ant` files and structure and how they end up building the deliverables?

Answer (score 6):

You can try this tools:

- [ant2dot](http://ant2dot.sourceforge.net/#what) - using [GraphViz toolkit](http://www.graphviz.org) to generate the final graph;
- [Vizant](http://vizant.sourceforge.net/) - using [GraphViz toolkit](http://www.graphviz.org) to generate the final graph;
- [Grand](http://www.ggtools.net/grand/) - using [GraphViz toolkit](http://www.graphviz.org) to generate the final graph;
- [ant-script-visualizer](http://code.google.com/p/ant-script-visualizer/) - using [GraphViz toolkit](http://www.graphviz.org) to generate the final graph.

The [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) has a very good support (has native plugin and several 3rd party plugins) of *Apache Ant*. You can read about [Ant support in IDEA here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/ant_maven.html).

Comment: Do you recommend one?I.e. have you used any of these?

Comment: I did not used any of them. I usually use the *IntelliJ IDEA* for working with *Ant* scripts.

Answer (score 1):

At my work we've had good results with [Grand.](http://www.ggtools.net/grand/)

Here is [another link](http://www.scmgalaxy.com/apache-ant/flow-diagram-and-gui-tools-for-apache-ant.html) to various Ant visualization tools.

Comment: How do I use grand?It says there is no `main`

Comment: I've only used the Ant task, not the standalone GUI app - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

yWorks AntExplorer is great but officially not around anymore.
see =
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2261205/130683
https://stackoverflow.com/a/458724/130683
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9184562/130683
But there is a [plugin for IntelliJ IDEA](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=135) available and you will
still find some sources for the standalone version, f.e. [here](http://blogstorage.chaiware.org/files-1/Antexplorer.V1.03.zip)